# Sum of multiple fields in a sub-document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have using the schema as suggested in the following link:
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/

Following is the sample document. The keys extends to 0 to 23 for hours and 0 to 59 for minutes in each hour. Some of the keys may be missing due to probability of pre-allocation.

```
{
  "page": "abc",
  "minute": {
    "0": {
      "0": 1,
      "1": 2,
      "2": 4,
      "3": 1,
      "4": 6
    },
    "1": {
      "0": 2,
      "1": 4,
      "2": 1,
      "3": 3,
      "4": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "0": 1,
      "1": 2,
      "2": 2,
      "3": 1,
      "4": 50
    },
    "3": {
      "0": 6,
      "1": 0,
      "2": 0,
      "3": 0,
      "4": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I want to calculate sum of visits from minute.2.30 to minute.3.15 per page.

Comment: You should summarize the relevant parts of the linked document in your question. Most people will probably not want to spent a lot of time on reading this entire page just to understand your example.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it using "$project" stage of the aggregation framework. I am using a combination of "$add" and "$ifNull" operators. Operator "$ifNull" is used to handle scenarios where the key of the sub document does not exist in the document.

```
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "page": 1,
    "number": {
      "$add": [
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.30", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.31", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.32", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.33", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.34", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.35", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.36", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.37", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.38", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.39", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.40", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.41", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.42", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.43", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.44", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.45", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.46", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.47", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.48", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.49", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.50", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.51", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.52", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.53", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.54", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.55", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.56", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.57", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.58", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.2.59", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.0", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.1", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.2", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.3", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.4", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.5", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.6", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.7", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.8", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.9", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.10", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.11", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.12", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.13", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.14", 0 ] },
        { "$ifNull": [ "$minute.3.15", 0 ] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```